Difference between `using` and `using namespace` declarations
(1)
namespace X {
  int i = 5;
}

int main()
{
  using X::i;
  
  i = 10;
  std::cout << i << '\n';     // 10
  std::cout << X::i << '\n';  // 10

  // int i = 22; 
  // error: 'int i' conflicts with a previous declaration
}

(2)
namespace X {
  int i = 5;
}

int main()
{
  using namespace X;

  int i = 10;
  std::cout << i << '\n';     // 10
  std::cout << X::i << '\n';  // 5
}

Question : Why we can not declare local i variable in (1) but can in (2).

(3)
  int i = 11; 

  namespace X {
    int i = 22;
  }

  using namespace X;
  
  int main()
  {
    std::cout << ::i << '\n';  // 11
    std::cout << X::i << '\n'; // 22

    // i = 33; 
    // error : reference to 'i' is ambiguous
  }

Question: Why assigning to i is ambigious in (3)

The two have completely distinct semantics. A bit simplified:
A using declaration makes it (roughly) so as if the named declarations were (also) placed in the scope of the using declaration itself at the point where the using declaration appears. They can conflict with other declarations in that scope. (Conflicts between the declarations imported in this way themselves are permitted though.)

A using namespace directive does not introduce any declarations that could conflict like this, but instead only makes all declarations in the named namespace visible to name lookup, if that lookup happens from a lookup context in which the using directive is reachable, as if they were placed in the inner-most namespace scope that encloses both the named namespace and the scope in which the using namespace directive appears.
For example in (2) if you try ::i in main this doesn't work because lookup context for i is the global namespace scope where the directive is not reachable.
And for example in (2) i is not ambiguous because the local variable int i = 10; is in a more-inner scope than the inner-most enclosing scope mentioned above, which would be the global namespace scope.
In case of qualified lookup, searches in each scope are first performed ignoring using namespace directives and only if that doesn't yield any results is their behavior mentioned above considered. (So ::i in (3) is not ambiguous. The declaration at global namespace scope is preferred over lookup through using namespace.)
In case of unqualified lookup, they are considered immediately, so that the lookup result can be ambiguous if there are other declarations with the same name in the same scope where the declarations made available through using namespace would appear. (So i = 33 in (3) is ambiguous since it finds both the variable at global scope and the one found through the using directive as if at the same scope.)
The behavior you see in your examples follows from that.

"they were placed in the inner-most namespace scope " what does this even mean? I know cppreference also has same wording, is there an example you can provide which explains what inner-most?

@ShivanshuArora Example: namespace A { namespace B { namespace C { } } } namespace D { using namespace B::C; } }. The scopes form a tree of scopes that enclose one-another. For example C is enclosed by B, A and the global namespace scope. The using namespace directive inhabits the scope of D. D does not enclose the scope B::C named in the directive. The immediate parent scope of D is A and A also encloses C. There is no scope between the using directive and A that also encloses C and therefore the inner-most enclosing namespace scope is A.

so if i have this namespace A{int i;} int main() {using namespace A;}, in this, I am doing using inside main, but A and main have same parent which is global namespace, does this mean inner-most enclosing namespace is global? If yes, then i should be able to do ::i inside main, but I can't

@ShivanshuArora Yes, it is the global namespace scope. ::i doesn't work because that is qualified lookup of i or rather, it performs a lookup of i from the lookup context of the global scope rather than the current scope. I mentioned unqualified lookup explicitly in my answer because of that. I clarified it now that it is important from which lookup context the lookup is performed.

oh i see...that's why you can use i as is if you want, but if you re-declare like int i;, now you can only access it using A::i so unqualified now maps to the local scope definition

@ShivanshuArora I have added some more clarifications. The exact lookup rules are unfortunately relatively complicated. But there is a significant difference between qualified and unqualified lookup that I didn't make clear earlier.

Perhaps worth mentioning more prominently that using A::i; is a declaration, but using namespace A; is a not a declaration, but a directive.

@j6t A using directive is also a declaration, both in the grammatical meaning as well as the semantic one. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-5.1, https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:block-declaration. It is just not a using-declaration. I am not aware that the term "directive" has a specific meaning in the C++ standard. It is only used as an arbitrary differentiator for the names of different constructs.


Question: Why assigning to i is ambigious in (3)

In (3) as you have using namespace X; in file scope, when you say i it is not clear which one of X::i or the global variable i is the one you are accessing.
